# Immer React Native Redux Nested Object

Tags: reactjs, react-native, object, redux, immer.js

When I run the following line even though mountain and lift are passed in this doesn't do anything:

```
draftState.resortNotifications[`${action.mountain}`][`${action.lift}`] = true;
```

If I run this I see it in my redux store:

```
draftState.resortNotifications[`${action.mountain}`] = true;
```

I am trying to use immer for this sole reason of nested objects.  I feel like is a basic elementary JS error.  I have tried `.push({[action.mountain]: true})` as well and this does nothing.  This object is not available yet/ I am adding to both mountain and lift for the first time.  I have used alerts to make sure both actions are passed in correctly.

```
import * as types from "./actionTypes";
import produce from 'immer';

const initialState = {
  resortNotifications: {}
};

const mountainInfo =
  produce(
    (draftState, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case types.RESORT_NOTIFICATIONS_LIFT_SUCCESS:
          draftState.resortNotifications[`${action.mountain}`][`${action.lift}`] = true;
          break;
      }
    },
    initialState
  )

export default mountainInfo;
```

Comment: What does your data look like? Do you actually have nested fields in your data that you can update? Immer doesn't magically populate nested objects - they have to exist first.

Comment: Two other notes on the code itself. First, using template literal strings _and_ interpolation is useless here. Those values are _already_ strings - you just need `[action.mountain]`, etc. Second, [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org) already has Immer built in, and will let you simplify this reducer definition as well as auto-generating all your action creators for you.

Comment: I don't have any data yet, this is trying to add an object- you can see initial state is ```resortNotifications: {}``` 
 I am storing this data in firebase and it will be in same structure.  I would have thought  ```draftState.resortNotifications[action.mountain][action.lift] = true ``` would add a value of true so that the object would now be ```{resortNotifications: {mountain: {lift: true}}}```. I am not sure why that doesn't work

Comment: It would be great to use the package you noted as well, but I don' really want to refractor the whole app at this point as that is a bigger overhaul than just implementing immer for this reducer.  I am using Object.assign or the spread operator in all my other reducers.  This is the first time I am using nested objects.

Comment: When I run the above command resortNotifications remains an empty object.  I am just not sure why it wouldn't add a value there. 
 ```resortNotifications: {}```

Comment: Yes, as the accepted answer shows, you can't access nested fields in objects that don't exist yet. Like I said, Immer doesn't magically create those objects - it just simplifies the process of updating existing objects. As for RTK, you can use it incrementally, in exactly the same way you were starting to use Immer for this one reducer. Just import `createSlice` for this one file and use it here. (Also, you should switch out the store setup logic for RTK's `configureStore` API, as that will add helpful dev check middleware that catches accidental mutations.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you try to access content that is not declared yet try this:

```js
import * as types from "./actionTypes";
import produce from 'immer';

const initialState = {
  resortNotifications: {}
};

const mountainInfo =
  produce(
    (draftState, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case types.RESORT_NOTIFICATIONS_LIFT_SUCCESS:
          if (!draftState.resortNotifications[action.mountain]) {
            draftState.resortNotifications[action.mountain] = {};
          }
          draftState.resortNotifications[action.mountain][action.lift] = true;
          break;
      }
    },
    initialState
  )

export default mountainInfo;
```